# How do I Throttle BrowserSync's speed?

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync, bandwidth-throttling

How can I configure BrowserSync (from its API) to serve up content at a slower rate?

Ideally I'd like to be able to serve only certain files at the throttled rate, so when developing, `localhost/index.html` loads fast and `localhost/dummyData.json` loads slowly, so I can effectively demo loading states while developing web apps that decouple data and presentation.

Comment: reloadThrottle: 300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. start browser-sync:
   `browser-sync start --server --files "src/*.*"`
2. open the browser-sync UI (e.g. http://localhost:300**1**/) and go to "Network Throttle"
   [image]
3. select "Speed", then "Create Server"
4. Use the new server instance which is now running at the defined speed

HINT:

You can run multiple throttled server instances an the same time - eg. to simulate CDN behavior (where the fastest wins)

You can also simulate latency! Have a look at the [bs-latency Plugin](https://github.com/BrowserSync/bs-latency) ...

Comment: if someone knows how to create throttled browser-sync instances programmatically, please let me know.

Comment: I haven’t tried it myself yet so I won’t answer, but it looks like you could copy the code in https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/tree/master/packages/browser-sync-ui/lib/plugins/network-throttle to try programmatic throttling

Answer (score -1):

From documentation

**reloadThrottle**

Emit only the first event during sequential time windows of a specified duration.

**Example**

```
browserSync.init({
        reloadThrottle: 300,
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dev/'
        }
    });
```